# What is the idiomatic way to iterate over a result set without loading all results at once using Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, pagination

Suppose I have a query object like this:

```
final SQLQuery query = createQuery(); // org.hibernate.SQLQuery
// HibernateTransaction is just a wrapper around Hibernate's Transaction, Session and
// SessionFactory classes

// the corresponding method:
private SQLQuery createQuery(HibernateTransaction t) {
    final SQLQuery query = t.fullSQLQuery(MY_QUERY_STRING);
    query.addScalar("column1", Hibernate.LONG);
    query.addScalar("column2", Hibernate.LONG);
    query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MyDTO.class));
    return query;
}
```

The `SQLQuery` object has a method called `iterate()`. My problem is that If I try to do something like this:

```
Iterator<MyDTO> iterator = query.iterate();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    MyDTO dto = iterator.next();
    // ...
}
```

I get an exception that iteration is not supported. If I use the `query.list()` method then I get a `List<MyDTO>` which is nice but If my query returns a million rows it gets slow and eventually runs out of memory.

My question is that what is the idiomatic way using Hibernate to only fetch a row at a time and lazily iterate over them? In my example I try to process the data in a table row by row.

I was thinking about using clustered indexes and only query like 1000 rows once and the next 1000 will be based on the last id of the previous 1000 (so basically I was thinking about pagination) but we are using MyISAM tables which are not supporting this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setMaxResults()` and `setFirstResult()` methods from SQLQuery class. They allow you to emulate both `offset` and `limit` SQL clauses.

If you wish to load results from rownum = 0 to rownum = 50, for instance, you would use `setFirstResult(0)` and `setMaxResults(50)` and so on.

Source: [Hibernate Javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Query.html)

Comment: Because `setMaxResults()` explicitly defines the number of rows the query will return at most.

Comment: I know but how can I tell how many times I have to repeat this process? So for example: `setFirstResult(1)`, `setFirstResult(51)` and so on. Or I just run a separate `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` query?

Comment: As long as I know, you can't retrieve the total row count with these objects, so you would need a separate `SELECT COUNT` query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can implemen paggination using `setMaxResults()` and `setFirstResult()` methods of `org.hibernate.SQLQuery` you have to write something like

```
// the corresponding method:
private SQLQuery createQuery(HibernateTransaction t,int lowLimit,int pageSize) {
    final SQLQuery query = t.fullSQLQuery(MY_QUERY_STRING);
    query.addScalar("column1", Hibernate.LONG);
    query.addScalar("column2", Hibernate.LONG);
    query.setFirstResult(lowLimit);
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MyDTO.class));
    return query;
}
```

and the loop as follows

```
int pageSize = 10;
int lowLimit = 0;
while(lowLimit != -1) {
    int size;
    List<MyDTO> list = query.list();
    size = list.size();
    //prosess your list here
    processResult(list);    
    if(pageSize != size) {
        lowLimit = -1;  
    } else {
      lowLimit = lowLimit + pageSize;   
    }
}
```

so this loop will first fetch 10 records then increment the counter by 10 this loop will continue until all records not get fetched as I am not sure about the result as I have not tested this code but should work...